# Find index from dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am working with Olympic.csv. In this csv there have country name and number of medal(Gold,silver,Bronze) they obtain from Summer and winter tournament. I am trying to find the **"Which country had the biggest difference between their summer and winter gold medal counts."**
Here Gold=summer and Gold.1=winter. I can find the differences medal count in integer value but can't find the index(country) name. Using google colab
My approaches

```
value1=df['Gold']
value2=df['Gold.1']
value3=value1-value2
value4=np.max(value3)
value4
```

Output: 820

Expected Output: Country name.

another Approaches

```
c=df['Gold']-df['Gold.1']
c.max()
```

Output: 820

Expected output: Country name

My question is how can i find index name?(using pandas if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your df is built, the easiest way will be (**if the names of the countries are your indices**) is to use: `df.idxmax()` after subtracting the columns like you did

from the documentation:

> Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.

[link to the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

EDITED:
The authors requested a more through explanation, consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd    
data = [['USA',11, 10], ['UK', 12, 15], ['IL', 9, 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Countries','Gold', 'Gold1']).set_index('Countries', drop=True)
```

this will result in the following DF:

```
           Gold  Gold1
Countries             
USA          11     10
UK           12     15
IL            9     14
```

now using your logic we will do the subtraction operations like so:

```
df2 = df['Gold']-df['Gold1']
```

and then use the `df.idxmax()`
and the output will be:

```
print(df2.idxmax())
#OUTPUT:
USA
```

Comment: Yes the country names are indices. Can you demonstrate how i should use idxmax()?

Comment: I have edited my answer and inserted an example :) In the example I added - USA has a score of 1 while the others have a negative score, hence USA is the output

Answer (score 0):

Try using np.argmax(). You will get index. Then the country at that index is your answer.

You might want to use the absolute value of difference. abs()